# FP Growth algorithm in spark using Hive table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-mllib

The following is my code to generate frequent itemsets from hive table

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Recommender").setMaster("local")
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc)
import hiveContext.implicits._
import hiveContext.sql

val schema = new StructType(Array(
StructField("col1", StringType, false)
))

val dataRow = hiveContext.sql("select col1 from hive_table limit 100000").cache()
val dataRDD = hiveContext.createDataFrame(dataRow.rdd,schema).cache()
dataRDD.show()

val transactions = dataRDD.map((row:Row) => {
val stringarray=row.getAs[String](0).split(",")
var arr=new Array[String](stringarray.length)
for( a <- 0 to arr.length-1) {
  arr(a)=stringarray(a)
}
arr
})

val fpg = new FPGrowth().setMinSupport(0.1).setNumPartitions(10)
val model = fpg.run(transactions)
val size: Double = transactions.count()
println("MODEL FreqItemCount "+model.freqItemsets.count())
println("Transactions count : "+size)
```

But the FreqItemCount always turns out to be 0.

The input query result is as shown below

```
270035_1,249134_1,929747_1
259138_1,44072_1,326046_1
385448_1,747230_1,74440_1,68096_1,610434_1,215589_3,999507_1,74439_1,36260_1,925018_1,588394_1,986622_1,64585_1,942893_1,5421_1,37041_1,52500_1,4925_1,553613           415353_1,600036_1,75955_1
693780_1,31379_1
465624_1,28993_1,1899_2,823631_1
667863_1,95623_3,345830_8,168966_1
837337_1,95586_1,350341_1,67379_1,837347_1,20556_1,17567_1,77713_1,361216_1,39535_1,525748_1,646241_1,346425_1,219266_1,77717_1,179382_3,702935_1
249882_1,28977_1
78025_1,113415_1,136718_1,640967_1,787444_1
193307_1,266303_1,220199_2,459193_1,352411_1,371579_1,45906_1,505334_1,9816_1,12627_1,135294_1,28182_1,132470_1
526260_1,305646_1,65438_1
```

But when i'm executing the code with the following hardcoded input, i'm getting proper frequent itemsets

```
val transactions = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  Array("Tuna", "Banana", "Strawberry"),
  Array("Melon", "Milk", "Bread", "Strawberry"),
  Array("Melon", "Kiwi", "Bread"),
  Array("Bread", "Banana", "Strawberry"),
  Array("Milk", "Tuna", "Tomato"),
  Array("Pepper", "Melon", "Tomato"),
  Array("Milk", "Strawberry", "Kiwi"),
  Array("Kiwi", "Banana", "Tuna"),
  Array("Pepper", "Melon")
))
```

Can you please let me know what am i doing wrong? I'm using spark 1.6.2 with scala 2.10.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the source of the problem is too high a support threshold (0.1). Value you use is pretty high and unlikely to be observed in the real life transaction data. Try to gradually reduce it, up to the point where you start to get the rules.